# Excel 2010 Count down two numbers based on available percentage

Tags: excel, formula

Aloha All,
I'm trying to express the following in an Excel formula/calculator:

1. I have a gumball machine with Pink and Green gumballs.
2. I can place as many of each color into the machine as I want.
3. A dial on the gumball machine can be set from 0% to 100%.
4. As long as the number of Pink gumballs is above the percentage on the dial the machine will release one Pink and one Green gumball per turn.
5. If it runs out of Green gumballs it will begin to dispense two Pink gumballs per turn until it reached the set percentage.
6. If there's a remainder of one Pink gumball to reach the set percentage it will release two Pink gumballs.
7. Once below the set percentage the machine will dispense one Pink gumball until all Pink gumballs are gone. Any Green gumballs left over will be held in reserve.
8. When Pink gumballs reach 0% the machine will release two Green gumballs at a time until all gumballs are gone.

**How many times do I need to push the button to get all the gumballs???**

EXAMPLES: 
I fill the machine with 100 Pink and 10 Green gumballs and set the dial to 70%.
I fill the machine with 48 Pink and 32 Green gumballs and set the dial to 80%.

I've been experimenting with this puzzle for two weeks without success. I've come close but still seem to get hiccups. Especially when getting close to 0 gumballs.

Comment: what have you done to get close ?

Comment: This is really a mathematical question. You have a system whose state after n turns is denoted by the number of pink and green balls `(P(n), G(n))`, the system starts in known state `(P(0), G(0))` and has function `f` which describes what happens at each turn, so `((P(n+1),G(n+1)) = f(P(n), G(n))`.  `f(,)` utilises various rules based on `P(n)/P(0)` and its relation to the dial setting `d`. Your question is really, given `P(0)`, `G(0)`, `d` and `f(,)` what is `N` such that `(P(N),G(N)) = (0,0)`? Fully specifying  `f(,)` - at present there are some ambiguities - should be your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

So the method that I finally found to work for me is

=ROUNDDOWN(Pink/2+Green/2+Percentage/200*100)

How does this compare to the math route you were working through? Is there a better option?

Comment: So what happens if, for example,  you fill with 50 Pink, 0 Green and you set the percentage to 80% (so that the no.of pinks corresponding to this percentage is 40.) For the first 5 turns, rule 5 applies, after that rule 7 for the next 40 turns, so 45 turns in total. Your formula indicates either 25 or 65 (depending on whether percentage is interepreted as 80 or 0.8.

Comment: Ugh. This puzzle... fun but annoying.

Comment: There's no rule covering the case what happens when the no. of pinks exactly equals the set percentage (Rule 5 covers above set percentage, Rule 7 below). I assumed Rule 7 in my counter example but it would still be a counter example if I had assumed  either Rule 5 or Rule 6 governs the sixth turn. Once the transition function is unambiguously specified, you can then implement in Excel as a turn-by-turn solution to examine wide range of cases and try to work out from your results what pattern exists and if there is a generally applicable formula.